# Url to Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I really don't know how to start this one, but here's the thing:

I have an `Shiny App` and i'd like to know how to make it run with an query (i don't know if it's right) from an `URL`.

For example:
When visiting the website, the person will click on a button, that has the parameters (ex: http://website.com/api/v1/search?lookfor=stackoverflow )

And i'd like it to redirect to the `Shiny App Page`, also with the `URL` as an value inside the Shiny App.

Any ideas how to do it or where to look for this kind of info?

Comment: What website? The shiny app?

Comment: No! A different one...

Comment: Are you are asking how to hyperlink your app on a website?

Comment: Is it? I don't know exactly, sorry about that... but it's like if you click here "Add coment" it would redirect to the page, but also with the values of the url of the button (needed to do the data manipulation)

Comment: I see, this is like ad-Tracking. If a user clicks on a link on a website, it redirects them to your application, as well as saving the URL they came from originally?

Comment: the URL has an csv file, that should be manipulated to be shown inside the app... here's an example of the url:
http://bdtd.ibict.br/vufind/api/v1/search?lookfor=astrof%C3%ADsica&type=AllFields&limit=1000&csv=true

Comment: http://bdtd.ibict.br/vufind/Search/Results?lookfor=astrof%C3%ADsica&type=AllFields&limit=20&sort=relevance

and here's the website... it is and option from "Exportar" and then "Export csv", but it would be another button with that info